# scrbook: no period in chapter heading but period in running header

Tags: formatting, header-footer, scrbook

In the scrbook class, is it possible to have a chapter heading prefixed with the word "chapter" and **without** period (i.e. "Chapter 1 The first chapter"), but in the running header **with** period (i.e. "Chapter 1. The first chapter")? In the KOMA documentation, the options I  found to turn off the period (`noendperiod`) or to turn it on (`endperiod`) affect both the chapter heading and the running header at the same time.

In the MWE, see the chapter heading on p.1, and the running header on p.2:

```
\documentclass[openright,chapterprefix=true,appendix,numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most simple answer would be to redefine `\chaptermarkformat`.

```
\documentclass[openright,chapterprefix=true,appendix,numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp\ \thechapter. }
\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```